# Последовательная загрузка файлов React

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Я использую react hook form для свой формы. В форме есть четыре поля textarea и один input type="file". Вот дефолтные значения моих полей при открытии окна формы:

```
{title: '', category: '', description: '', specification: '', uploadFile: Array(0)}
```

Я добился корректной работы всех textarea, а так же их валидации в зависимости от введенного текста, и т.д. Важно - все мои поля textarea и input являются обязательными. Серьезной проблемой для меня стала загрузка файлов. По логике программы пользователь может подгружать файлы в форму несколько раз ДО сабмита формы. Я сделал свой компонент таким:

```
import IconContainer from "../IconContainer/IconContainer";
import { UseFormWatch, UseFormSetValue, UseFormReset, Control, Controller, FieldErrorsImpl } from "react-hook-form";
import { UserSubmitForm } from "../../interfaces/inputs";

interface FileInputsProps {
  watch: UseFormWatch<UserSubmitForm>;
  setValue: UseFormSetValue<UserSubmitForm>
  reset: UseFormReset<UserSubmitForm>
  control: Control<UserSubmitForm>
  errors: Partial<FieldErrorsImpl<UserSubmitForm>>
}

const FileInputs = ({ errors, setValue, control, watch }: FileInputsProps) => {
  const allValue = watch();
  console.log(allValue);
  console.log(errors);

  const validateFile = (v:any[]): boolean => {
    return false;
  };

  return (
    <div className="modal__formItem">
      <label className="modal__input modal__input_files" htmlFor="formId">
        <IconContainer icon={"material-symbols:add"} sizeWidth={"15"} sizeHeight={"15"} />
        <Controller
          name="uploadFile"
          control={control}
          rules={{
            required: {value: true, message: "Обязательное поле"},
            validate: (v) => validateFile(v),
          }}
          render={({ field: { value, name } }) => {
            return (
              <input
                id="formId"
                name={name}
                type="file"
                multiple
                hidden
                onChange={e => {
                  if (e.target) {
                    if (e.target.files) {
                      setValue("uploadFile", [...value, e.target.files[0]]);
                    }
                  }
                }}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
        Добавить файл
      </label>
      <span className="modal__input-limit">pdf, excel, pptx</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileInputs;
```

Первая проблема с которой я столкнулся - это некорректная валидация поля загрузки файла. Как видите я попытался принудительно запретить валидацию, попробовав возвращать `false` из `validateFile`. Даже при таком ручном запрете, если я ничего не ввожу в textarea и нажимаю submit я получаю корректную валидацию. В консоли при этом я вижу следующее:
Функция Watch() показывает мне корректный список полей, а значит и их регистрацию:

```
{title: '', category: '', description: '', specification: '', uploadFile: Array(0)}
```

Но вот попытка просмотреть errors выводит вот такие данные:

```
{title: {…}, category: {…}, description: {…}, specification: {…}}
```

Т.е. ошибки uploadFile просто нет при первом submit. Если же нажать submit второй раз, то в errors поле uploadFile появляется:

```
category
: 
{type: 'required', message: 'Обязательное поле', ref: {…}}
description
: 
{type: 'required', message: 'Обязательное поле', ref: {…}}
specification
: 
{type: 'required', message: 'Обязательное поле', ref: {…}}
title
: 
{type: 'required', message: 'Обязательное поле', ref: {…}}
uploadFile
: 
{type: 'required', message: 'Обязательное поле', ref: {…}}
```

Вот ссылка на песочницу. https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-glade-hhhbdo
Как мне корректно валидировать данную форму, чтобы сабмит не срабатывал при первом нажатии

Comment: не полностю разобрал, попробуй по точнее описать, либо кодом.

Comment: Ну если совсем просто - есть у вас кликер, т.е. <input type="file"/>. Кликаете вы по нему один раз, находите файл, нажимаете в диалоговом окне "Выбрать". Файл сохраняется на front`e (Где?). Гажимаете еще раз. Снова открывается диалоговое окно. Снова выбираете файл, уже второй. Он так же сохраняется как и первый на фронте. В данной форме помимо <input type="file"/> есть и <textarea />. Смысл в том, что бы сохранить как-то и где-то выбранные файлы, а потом, когда мы сабмитим форму, наши файлы отправились бы на сервер неким массивом(?).

Answer (score 1):

полноценный рабочий пример, типизацию только убрал.

```js
export const App = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit, formState, watch } = useForm();

  const handleFormSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
    console.log({ data });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          handleFormSubmit(e);
        }}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          gap: 20,
          maxWidth: 400,
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <FileFormInput control={control} name="file" />
        <TextFormInput control={control} name="name" />
        <TextFormInput control={control} name="surname" />
        <button>submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const FileFormInput: FC = ({ control, name: propsName }) => {
  const {
    field: { onChange, value, name },
    fieldState: { error },
  } = useController({
    control,
    name: propsName,
    defaultValue: [],
    rules: {
      required: {
        message: "required",
        value: true,
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <label
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          border: "1px solid black",
          position: "relative",
        }}
      >
        заполни меня
        <input
          type={"file"}
          multiple
          style={{
            opacity: "0",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
          }}
          name={name}
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e.target?.files?.[0]) {
              if (value?.length) {
                return onChange([...value, ...Array.from(e.target.files)]);
              }
              return onChange([e.target.files[0]]);
            }
          }}
        />
      </label>
      {error?.message && (
        <span
          style={{
            color: "red",
          }}
        >
          {error.message}
        </span>
      )}
      {value?.map(({ name }) => name).join(", ")}
    </div>
  );
};

const TextFormInput = ({ control, name: propsName }) => {
  const {
    field,
    fieldState: { error },
  } = useController({
    control,
    name: propsName,
    defaultValue: "",
    rules: {
      required: {
        message: "required",
        value: true,
      },
    },
  });
  return (
    <label>
      <input type="text" {...field} />
      {error?.message && (
        <span
          style={{
            color: "red",
          }}
        >
          {error.message}
        </span>
      )}
    </label>
  );
};
```

Comment: Добавил конкретики в вопросе + codesanbox

Comment: @elarri, на верху полноценно рабочий пример, если интересует почему конкретно в той реализации которая у тебя есть что то не работает минимизируй максимально пример, лень же смотреть все файлы что куда где), хотя Controller конкретно я не юзаю, может что то спецефичное.

Comment: Если честно, я в ступоре. Вчера сделал все по твоему примеру и о чудо - все сработало. Сегодня просто перезапускаю проект без каких либо изменений (!!!) npm start и загрузка опять не работает. Какой-то бред...

Comment: @elarri да что то странное, скинь какие ошибки, может что то проеснится.

Comment: @elarri кстати это чисто рукаписный пример, но есть либы в  npm dropzone и тд, которые те уже дают инкапсулировано это все, просто надо связать с use-form

Comment: а можешь сказать парочку либ. Насчет ошибок - не знаю, т.к. ошибок нет ни в консоли, ни при запуске. Но у меня проблема была с node.js, т.ч. попробую развернуть на рабочей машине и проверить. Если и там не полетит, буду проовать либы использовать. Может подскажешь какие-нибудь, чтобы валидация была на стороне react-hook-form, а загрузка нескольких файлов - на стороне самой библиотеки?

Comment: Кажется, я нашел. Поведение данного фрагмента кода отличается от версии react-hook-form. Так, например, в версии 7.40.0 не работает ничего. В 7.39.7
 работает required фала... сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Всегда срабатывает условие return onChange([e.target.files[0]]); При этом value не меняется. Таким образом value остается пустым массивом...

Comment: @elarri react-dropzone, где то 4-5 месяца назад юзал, спакойно стикуется с react-hook-form.

Comment: @elarri кстати валидацию можно через yup делать, удобная штука.